# Displaying a legend in a line chart using Telerik UI for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, telerik

How can I display a legend in a line chart using Telerik's UI for Xamarin?

Is it possible to accomplish this without creating a customer renderer?

Thanks for the help,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

That isn't implemented into the Xamarin.Forms package for Telerik charts yet.

You can either make a custom renderer to use the platform specific legends, or you can just code in your own Labels/Buttons that look and act like a legend.